# OpenCV Configuration error with VS 2012

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, environment-variables

I use windows 8 **64x** Version but My Visual Studio 2012 is **86x**

When I create Environmental Variable Should I use 86x or 64x ?

which one from the following should I use for Environmental variable path ?

```
 C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin
```

or

```
C:\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin
```

Comment: x86 should be the only working one for you

Comment: check, what *configuration* you*re compiling, and set the path approriate to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use 86x

The reason being that MSVS needs a 64x compiler to build 64 bit applications which it may not have.